# SQL server Merge two xmls into a third

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I am working in SQL Server 2008. I have output from for xml explicit queries in two xml variables. My SP has to combine both the xmls into a well formed third xml. Illustration given below. No complex processing is involved.

I like to merge two xmls present in two xml variables into a single xml

Suppose
First XML (@x)

```
<Student>
<Name>Lawy</Name>
<class>form1</class>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Vina</Name>
<class>form2</class>
</Student>
```

Second XML (@y)

```
<Dept>
<DeptName>Social</DeptName>
<centre>AOS</centre>
</Dept>
<Dept>
<DeptName>Bio</DeptName>
<centre>RJS</centre>
</Dept>
```

The resultant I want is (@z)

```
<sp>
  <Student>
   <Name>Lawy</Name>
   <class>form1</class>
  </Student>
  <Student>
   <Name>Vina</Name>
   <class>form2</class>
  </Student>
  <Dept>
   <DeptName>Social</DeptName>
   <centre>AOS</centre>
  </Dept>
  <Dept>
   <DeptName>Bio</DeptName>
   <centre>RJS</centre>
  </Dept>
</sp>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @x xml
declare @y xml

select @x = '<Student>
<Name>Lawy</Name>
<class>form1</class>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Vina</Name>
<class>form2</class>
</Student>'

select @y = '<Dept>
<DeptName>Social</DeptName>
<centre>AOS</centre>
</Dept>
<Dept>
<DeptName>Bio</DeptName>
<centre>RJS</centre>
</Dept>'

select @x, @y for xml path('sp')
```

**update:** if you need attributes in your sp, you can do this

```
select 2 as [@id], @x, @y for xml path('sp')
```

Comment: almost exact answers :) nice. You have to admit, sometimes you beat me :)

Comment: Thank you guys! I just need to add a attribute <sp id="2">...<sp>. Please let me know how to do

Comment: @user881726 added attribute